# How and where can i freeze classifier layer?

Tags: python, pytorch

If I need to freeze the output layer of this model which is doing the classification as I don't need it.

Comment: How did you come up with this line: `model.classifier.weight.requires_grad_(False)`? When people walk about "freezing" a mode, it's usually for the purpose of fine-tuning the top-most classifier head. If you are following that case, then you'd want to freeze everything *except* the classifier head.

Comment: How did you find this `VisionTransformer` model? Was it from a course you're taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing a few things here (I think)

### Freezing layers

You freeze the layer if you don't want them to be trained (and don't want them to be part of the graph also).

Usually we freeze part of the network **creating features**, in your case it would be everything up to `self.head`.

After that, we usually only train bottleneck (`self.head` in this case) to **fine-tune it** for the task at hand.

In case of your model it would be:

```
def gradient(model, freeze: bool):
    for parameter in transformer.parameters():
        parameter.requires_grad_(not freeze)


transformer = VisionTransformer()
gradient(model, freeze=True)
gradient(model.head, freeze=False)
```

### I only want the features

In this case you have the following line:

```
self.head = nn.Linear(embed_dim, num_classes) if num_classes > 0 else nn.Identity()
```

If you specify `num_classes` as `0` the model will only return the  features, e.g.:

```
transformer = VisionTransformer(num_classes=0)
```

### I want specific head for my task

Simply override the `self.head` attribute, for example:

```
transformer.head = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(embed_dim, 100), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(100, num_classes)
)
```

Or, if you want different number of classes you can specify `num_classes` to the number of classes you have in your task.

### Question in the comment

No, you should freeze **everything except head** and specify that you want features out, this would do the trick:

```
def gradient(model, freeze: bool):
    for parameter in transformer.parameters():
        parameter.requires_grad_(not freeze)


transformer = VisionTransformer(num_classes=0)
gradient(model, freeze=True)
```

Due to that, learned features by VisionTransformer will be preserved (probably what you are after), **you don't need `self.head` at all in this case!**

Comment: @user VisionTransformer (if trained on a dataset) creates features. It was already trained so you don't have to train it (if you freeze it, this part of network will not be updated during training process). Hence you freeze the whole model. `self.head` is for classification specifically, you don't need that part of the network. After you get the features out of `VisionTransformer` you can apply your own neural network doing the captioning and train __only this part__ on the data you have.

Comment: i'm confusing between two statements `freeze everything except head` and `you don't need self.head at all in this case!`

Comment: i'm sorry for my lot questions and confusing

Comment: @user what is your task? Classification of images?

Comment: @user the last code snippet will do what you want then

Comment: thanks a lot but in the last code snippet  you freeze the classification layer by write num_class=0 right ? exucse me the last question is what is the difference between  `parameter.requires_grad_(not freeze)` and `gradient(model, freeze=True)`

Comment: `gradient(model, freeze=True)` is just a function going over all parameters of the network and freezing them. `num_class=0` will create an `nn.Identity` layer instead of `nn.Linear` for `self.head` (check the docs) which just forwards the input. Which essentially leaves you with the network __without `self.head`__.

Comment: great thanks can i take your email for further contact ! Appreciate your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233671/discussion-between-szymon-maszke-and-user).

Comment: can you see my update and check it if i'm right please

Comment: You can pass transformer as an argument and it will be named model, but other than that yes, that’s the idea